# Never close JDatePicker

Tags: java, swing, date, picker

I'm currently working on a java program which should be able to instantly show you appointments for a certain date. I chose JDatePicker for selecting the date. Now it is really annoying that the Date Picker closes every time you choose a date. Is there a workaround for that? And could you tell me if you can apply a OnChangeListener or something similar to the date picker?

My code:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("text.today", "Heute");
p.put("text.month", "Monat");
p.put("text.year", "Jahr");
UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new DateLabelFormatter());
add(datePicker);
```

**EDIT:
I'm using JCalender now and it works like a charm :)**

Comment: There's probably a way; could we see your code?

Comment: Sure, just added it :)

Comment: Which version of JDatePicker are you using?